# Animating Rating Bar Stars

Tags: java, android

I searched on internet for the answer but failed. The closest I got is:

```
int sc = total % 10;
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stars, "rating", stars.getRating(), 5f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
                switch (sc){
                    case 5:
                        stars.setRating(1);break;
                    case 6:
                        stars.setRating(1);break;
                    case 7:
                        stars.setRating(2);break;
                    case 8:
                        stars.setRating(2);break;
                    case 9:
                        stars.setRating(3);break;
                    case 0:
                        stars.setRating(3);break;
                }

                anim.start();
```

But it does not stop at 1 or 2 stars. It always completely fill the `ratingbar` with 3 stars.

Comment: Obviously, you need a break...

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: [lol, sorry about break stuff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B9V87A7wki3njLk-yCBrTf6ewpeCJHqu/view?usp=drives) I saw my mistake when I opened question in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stars, "Rating", stars.getRating(), 5f);
```

you are telling to objectAnimator to animate your ratingBar rating from starts.getRating() to 5 star rating  you should change  your code like below

```
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stars, "Rating",0, yourRate);
```

**Example :**

```
   myRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean fromUser) {

            if(fromUser)
            setRatingWithAnimation(v);

        }
    });


public void setRatingWithAnimation(float ratingWithAnimation) {

    ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(myRatingBar,"Rating",0,ratingWithAnimation)
            .setDuration(1000)
            .start();

}
```

Comment: Please, do not post code only... Provide also information about what is he eventually doing wrong, and why your code would eventually fix the issue.